# How to add cordova to existing angular project

Tags: angularjs, cordova, yeoman, ionic-framework

I've been searching high and low and couldn't get a direct answer or getting my code to work.

I have an existing `Angular` project that was started via `yeoman` with `Angular` and `PhoneGap` setup together. My setup uses `yo` and `bower` to generate the files.

I've tried to import certain cordova plugins to test out like the *camera* or *datepicker* and see if it works on the device but it doesn't as it was always saying the calling function is undefined.

So with the current setup I call the code below in one of my submodules

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess,onFail,{sourceType:1,quality:60});
```

This doesn't work so I tried other tutorials and also by trying ngCordova which is a wrapper class for angular. The following is how it looks like in my index.html

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/collide/collide.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb-nightly.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/proj4/dist/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
```

In the tutorials it's asking to  have the ng-cordova import above this line which does not exist

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

How do I generate this cordova.js into an existing project and will it conflict with the phonegap.js file?

Comment: you need to use either phonegap.js or cordova.js. if you are using phonegap then use phonegap.js, if you are using cordova then use cordova.js. If you are new to phonegap and cordova world and confused between phonegap and cordova,I will suggest t o read difference between both.

Comment: I have read about them both but phonegap is still pointing to cordova page when you import the plugins. So can I assume that phonegap.js can replace cordova.js?

Comment: not sure for latest versions, but all phonegap.js has been doing since version 3.0 is just load cordova.js...

Comment: How are you trying to integrate cordova in angular? Are you at any point using the cordova cli? I don't really know angular, but I think the way to do would be to integrate the angular project in cordova, not the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new project, add a platform (e.g. ios) with cordova and put the `cordova.js` file of it into your existing project.  Phonegap supports both `phonegap.js` and `cordova.js` as stated [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/134#issuecomment-22035314).  You'll find the file in `platforms/ios/www/cordova.js`.  Then, you're right, the `cordova.js` has to be included as the last `<script>` that you include.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be pointing me to the right direction but I notice that in my current project the cordova.js already exists in the platforms/ios/CordovaLib/ and platforms/ios/platform_www/ folders. So are you saying to copy the file from those folders and put it in the same folder with the phonegap.js? I seem to think maybe this is incorrect?

Comment: I've just tested copying the cordova.js from platforms/ios/CordovaLib/ to the same folder as the index.html and it's complaining about a linkage problem unable to access cordova_plugins.js. I don't think I should be copying all those dependency files out as well?

Comment: Yes you should. The `platforms/ios/www` folder of a normal cordova project has a `cordova.js` and a `cordova_plugins.js` file.